# Having issues in linking objective-c with golang 1.1 - was working with golang 1.1beta

Tags: objective-c, macos, go, cgo

Need help with linking objective-c in go.

Following objective-c code was working with golang 1.1beta but now it doesn't work with the latest go 1.1 release.

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Cocoa
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void
log(void) {
    NSLog(@"from objective-c");
}

*/
import "C"
func New() {
    C.log()
}
```

I get following errors when I run go install or go run :

```
(__DATA/__cfstring): unexpected reloc for dynamic symbol __CFConstantStringClassReference
(__DATA/__cfstring): unhandled relocation for __CFConstantStringClassReference (type 28 rtype 120)
```

Comment: This seems to be a on going issue. See https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1781 and https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported the issue [#5699](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5699), and it got fixed in Go v1.2.